# How to remove # from url in angular from deplyoed site

Tags: angular9

When I run angular application locally # gets removed from the url as I have made changes in app.module.ts, but when I deploy the project on the server PathLocationStrategy doesn't work, I get internal server error or page not found error or else # doesn't get removed from the URL.
How can I remove # from the deployed site?

Comment: check this out https://angular.io/guide/router#hashlocationstrategy

Comment: hi, I tried this but it didn't work @PalakJadav. Basically, I am deploying my project on IIS server and there I am facing this '#' issue.